# Создать связанный компонент при редактировании свойств другого компонента в Design Time

Tags: delphi, компоненты, vcl, delphi-10-seattle

Проектирую свой собственный новый визуальный компонент TSeqLink. У него, в числе прочих, есть свойство

```
published
property Handler: TLinkHandler read FHandler write SetLinkHandler;
```

которое указывает на также собственный невизуальный компонент TLinkHandler, отвечающий за обработку связей между экземплярами TSeqLink. 
После размещения на форме нового экземпляра TSeqLink пользователь должен будет в окне Object Inspector присвоить свойству Handler значение (если он хочет это сделать в Design-Time). Допустим, на форме уже размещен(ы) экземпляр(ы) TLinkHandler, тогда, чтобы выбирать значение среди них, я должен провести анализ всех компонентов на форме в процедуре SetlinkHandler. Как-то так:

```
with Owner do
if csDesigning in ComponentState then
begin
for i:=0 to ComponentCount-1 do
if Components[i] is TLinkHandler then
<обработка>
end;
```

Как быть, если экземпляров TLinkHandler на форме несколько? Как я должен обработать ситуацию, чтобы был список возможных вариантов? А если на форме нет ни одного экземпляра TLinkHandler, могу я каким-то образом тут же в Object Inspector'е создать новый экземпляр такового, чтобы он появился на форме?

Comment: Вам не удалось понятно объяснить, что Вам нужно. Попорбуйте еще раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Начнем с того, что в коде из вопроса (он находится внутри `TSeqLink.SetLinkHandler`, так?) для поиска экземпляров `TLinkHandler` у того же владельца Вам следует искать в компонентах владельца:

```
if csDesigning in ComponentState then
begin
  for i:=0 to Owner.ComponentCount-1 do
    if Owner.Components[i] is TLinkHandler then
      <обработка>
end;
```

Я все еще не понимаю, почему Вас не устраивает стандартное поведение дизайнера для связывания компонент - как, например, между `TDataSource`-ом и `TDataSet`-ами. Положите на форму один `TDataSource` и несколько `TClientDataSet`ов и посмотрите, что выпадает в свойстве `DataSource1.DataSet` в редакторе свойств.

*Update*

Вы так и не объяснили, зачем нужен целый метод для установки значения свойства:

```
property Handler: TLinkHandler read FHandler write FHandler;
```

Не забудьте переписать метод `Notification` в `TSeqLink`:

```
procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;

procedure TSeqLink.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); 
begin
  if (Operation = opRemove) and (AComponent = FHandler) then
    FHandler := nil;
  inherited;
end;
```

*Update*

Во-первых, следует определиться - на ком лежит ответственность за предоставление ссылки на `TLinkHandler`. Если на пользователе, который кладет компоненты на форму, то кода выше достаточно. Если это должен делать сам `TSeqLink`, то метод `SetLinkHandler` вызываться не будет и помещать туда код `<обработка>` не имеет смысла. Поэтому Вам нужно (хотя бы для себя) описать желаемое поведение - как устанавливается связка между Вашими компонентами.

Comment: да, разумеется, забыл добавить строку with Owner.  Исправил, спасибо.

Comment: Ну, почему же - стандартное поведение меня более или менее устраивает, хотя хотелось бы иметь возможность добавления нового компонента при отсутствии уже имеющихся. А поскольку у меня сейчас нет доступа к исходникам стандартных компонентов Delphi, я не могу до конца понять, как правильно написать обработку ситуации, т.е. что же должно быть вместо <обработка>. В сети пока не нашёл достаточно ответов.

Comment: "Целый метод" - я планировал в нем проверять находящиеся на форме компоненты и, в случае, отсутствия хотя бы одного экземпляра TLinkHandler на форме, создавать таковой.